# Laravel login, check if username and pwd are a match in my database

Tags: javascript, php, sqlite, laravel-5

In my login form all I need
is just username and a password ,trying to use ajax to get data from sqlite .

[image]

**.AJAX of my login.blade.php**

$(document).ready(function(){

```
  $("#login").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "UserController.php",
      data: { username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val()},
      success: function(data){

        response = JSON.parse(data);
        if(response[0]){

        }
        else{
          alert(response[1]);
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```

**my User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'phone','email', 'password','password_confirmation','librarian'
    ];


}
```

**read method in UserController**

```
//to read data from database to login
    public function read(Request $request){


        $results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);

        foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->username;
}
```

**my web.php**

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
});
Route::get('/signup',function(){
    return view('signup');
});
Route::get('/bookscreate',function(){
return view('bookscreate');
});

Route::get('/','BookController@index');
Route::post('signup', 'UserController@store');
//Route::post('signup', 'UserController@read');

Route::resource('/books','BookController');
```

So my objective is to go to my database table check username and password if they match one of the DB id then allow user to login .

Comment: Why not `php artisan make:auth`?

Comment: please explain how it would apply to my case ?, I kinda did some reading about auth but I not sure how to fetch data and use it .

Comment: that would make login and registration system. So you don't need to build or code for it.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication

read laravel authentication document because laravel have your requirement already built-in and it is very easy to implement. Thank you since i was not able to comment i had to post it as answer.

Comment: yeah ! not sure auth is gonna be super helpful .this is for a project and the way to do it ,is through AJAX and userController .

Comment: it can be done through ajax also instead of making form submit to web routes using ajax call and make a form submit it is still going to be the same all you do is modify the code according the ajax call. just a give it try